# What sense of the using "this" in the constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

Can someone expain, what sense of this construction?

```
public class A
{
    public A(): this("..") {}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`: this(…)` after the constructor calls *another* constructor with the specified arguments. For example:

```
public class A
{
    public A (string foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }

    public A () : this("foo bar")
    {}
}
```

This will allow you to create an object of `A` and pass a string to customize its output; or you can call it without arguments which causes the second constructor to be called which itself calls the first one with `"foo bar"` as the argument.

There is one other similar keyword which is used when `A` inherits from some other class. In that case, you can use `base` instead of `this` to directly call a constructor from the base class:

```
public class A : B
{
    public A () : base("foo bar")
    {}
}
```

So when you now create an object of `A`, the constructor of `A` will call a constructor of `B` that accepts a string and pass `"foo bar"` there.

For more information, see the [“Using constructors”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) section of the C# programming guide.

Answer (score 3):

If the parameter-less constructor is called it will call the constructor accepting a single string, passing `".."`.  In your case there is no such constructor though, so the code wont compile.